# Clicking on onboard steals dash's focus

Tags: unity-dash, focus, onboard

Is there any way to stop clicks on onboard from closing Dash?  I would like to be able to type in Dash using onboard before it disappears.  It even happens when focus prevention level setting in Compiz is set to 'Very high'.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known [bug](http://pad.lv/739812/). Sorry. The good news is that it will be fixed in 11.10 in 6 months but unfortunately it's unlikely to be fixed in 11.04. You could try using Ubuntu Classic instead if you need to use an onscreen keyboard.